# Passing props back everytime a from is submitted in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Dashboard` component which has 3 children `Search`, `MealList` and `UserData`.
I have 4 state variables, `fromDate`, `toDate`, `fromTime` and `toTime` which are initially set to null inside the `Dashboard`.
These are passed down to the `MealList` component as props.

```
const Dashboard = () => {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [calories, setCalories] = useState("");
    const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState(null);
    const [toDate, setToDate] = useState(null);
    const [fromTime, setFromTime] = useState(null);
    const [toTime, setToTime] = useState(null);

    useEffect(async () =>{
        const data = await fetchUserData(localStorage.getItem('email'));
        localStorage.setItem('user_id', data['id']);
        setUsername(data['username']);
        setEmail(data['email']);
        setCalories(data['calories']);
    }, []);

    const updateList = (fd, td, ft, tt) =>{
        setFromDate(fd);
        setToDate(td);
        setFromTime(ft);
        setToTime(tt);
    };
    console.log(fromDate);
    return (
        <div>
            <Navigation/>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div style={{display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'row wrap'}}>
                    <UserData username={username} email={email} calories={calories}/>
                    <Search onSubmit={updateList}/>
                </div>
                <MealList fromDate={fromDate} toDate={toDate} fromTime={fromTime} toTime={toTime}/>

            </div>

        </div>

    )
};
export default Dashboard;
```

The MealList component fetches data based on these 4 state variables.

```
const MealList = (props) => {
    const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
    useEffect(async () => {
        const mealsData = await fetchMeals(localStorage.getItem('user_id'), props.fromDate, props.toDate, props.fromTime, props.toTime);
        setMeals([...meals, ...mealsData]);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{width: '70%'}}>
            <h3 style={{color: 'grey', fontSize: '1.4em', fontWeight: '700', marginBottom: '1em'}}><FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faPlusCircle} style={{color: '#007bff', marginRight: '0.5em'}}/> ADD MEAL</h3>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Meal</th>
                    <th>Calories</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {meals.map((meal, index) => (<Meal count={index +1} meal={meal}/>))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>

    )
};
export default MealList;
```

These state variables are updated in the from submission inside `Search`, which calls the `updateList` function inside `Dashboard`. 
1. How do I pass these values back and re-render MealList everytime these `updateList` is called?
2. How do I nullify the meals array inside MealList and add the new set of values fetched?
This I believe will add values to the existing array.

```
const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
setMeals([...meals, ...mealsData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add all of the prop values as dependencies in your `useEffect` call within the `MealList` component.  With an empty dependency array, the function inside will only run once when the component mounts. By listing dependencies, it will run the fetch again when any of them change. Something like this:

```
 useEffect(async () => {
        const mealsData = await fetchMeals(localStorage.getItem('user_id'), props.fromDate, props.toDate, props.fromTime, props.toTime);
       // Assuming mealsData is an array of new values
        setMeals(mealsData);
    }, [props]);
```

I think that should cover all the changes.

**EDIT**: Don't list `meals` as a dependency, as it could cause an infinite loop.

Comment: I guess there's more, but that fetch definitely will not be updated without listing dependencies used within the effect. Your linter should flag that. Good luck.

Comment: B can you please take a look at the repo, https://github.com/melissa-stewart/mealplan